# Good practice to make Django forms.py DRY

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I had an idea about how to make my `forms.py` DRY but since I have never seen it elsewhere before, I'm questioning myself.

The whole purpose is to re-use form fields in different forms.

Here is what I'd like to do:

File: `form_fields.py`

```
EMAIL_FIELD = forms.EmailField(
    label="Adresse e-mail",
    widget=forms.TextInput(),
    error_messages=DICT_ERROR)

PASSWORD_FIELD = ...
```

File: `forms.py`

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    email = EMAIL_FIELD
    pwd = PASSWORD_FIELD
    ... etc.

class SigninForm(forms.Form):
    email = EMAIL_FIELD
    pwd = PASSWORD_FIELD
```

Is it OK to you? If it's not, what do you suggest to make a good "architecture" of a `forms.py` file which can grow a lot in my case?

In addition, I'm asking myself if I'm supposed to create only 1 field variable for fields that have same characteristics (e.g. first name and last name). In that case, how do you handle the different labels?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer made by user2032220 is good. Also instead of using EMAIL_FIELD, it's better to extend `forms.EmailField` class and apply your own default values for class:

```
class EmailField(forms.EmailField):
    """Your custom EmailField with best set of default kwargs"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('label', 'Adresse e-mail')
        kwargs.setdefault('widget', forms.TextInput())
        kwargs.setdefault('error_messages', DICT_ERROR)
        return super(EmailField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class BaseForm(forms.Form):
    email = EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        abstract=True

##Inherit BaseForm
class SignUpForm(BaseForm):
    ## Other attributes

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    # Easy way of changing just one parameter
    email = EmailField(label='Your email')
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Could you please both elaborate about why this solution is better? You're probably right but this is not obvious to me. Thanks again.

Comment: I gave example in the code with `EmailField(label='Your email')`. If you create your own field with default values in this way and you have to change just one of arguments (in my example just different label for ContactForm) you just overwrite one of kwargs instead of copy  pasting everything.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you can do it.

```
class BaseForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        abstract=True

##Inherit BaseForm
class SignUpForm(BaseForm):
    ## Other attributes
```

Comment: This is a more DRY way than the OPs